# Using ROBOCOPY to MOVE data around, not copy it

Tags: command-line-interface, powershell, robocopy

I have the following powershell script, which executes a few robocopy commands:

```
ROBOCOPY.exe $q3 $q4 /R:5 /W:15 /S /NP /MT:32 /XA:SH /XJD
ROBOCOPY.exe $q2 $q3 /R:5 /W:15 /S /NP /MT:32 /XA:SH /XJD
ROBOCOPY.exe $q1 $q2 /R:5 /W:15 /S /NP /MT:32 /XA:SH /XJD
ROBOCOPY.exe $src $q1 /R:5 /W:15 /S /NP /MT:32 /XA:SH /XJD
```

This works fine, but it takes a **really** long time, I'm wondering, if there is a way that I can have robocopy do a "cut + paste" instead of a "copy + paste" so windows will move the NTFS pointer to the file, instead of actually copying all of the bits of each file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/MOV` option is designed to do exactly that. Check your specific version of robocopy for it (robocopy /? should show the option).

[image]

Comment: RoboCopy.exe with /MOVE used to delete source files, but now it sees the source is the same as destination and leaves the source. Win2008r2.  MS knows there are problems with RoboCopy.  Very Disappointing.

Comment: not correct answer - robocopy with /MOV parameter actually copies&deletes files, instead of just moving and changing pointer. Which is the original question

Comment: yes, tested this in Windows 10 and robocopy is still copying files

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy only leaves empty source folders when using /MT (in my case 32) switch, if I don't use /MT everything is moved, running on 2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

[move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move) or [move-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item)

```
Move-Item -Path $source -Destination $source
```

I believe the existence of the [move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move) & [ren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ren) commands is part of the reason why robocopy doesn't move the pointer (robocopy wants to be robust & recoverable).

Might want to check if it was on the same logical drive on the same machine before deciding to use move or robocopy:

```
$source_root = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($source)
$dest_root = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($dest)
if($source_root -like $dest_root){...
```